# I try to connect enginne app with cloud sql

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, loopback

Connection fails: Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@xx.xx.xx.xx'.  My APP is development with Loopback4 and my database is MySQL.
I am using app engine and google cloud SQL.
I try to connect being on the same network through the private ip of my mysql instance

Comment: Which version of app engine (standard or flex), and could you post the code that's doing the connecting?

This page: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues has a lot of troubleshooting things you can go through to eliminate the "simple" things.

Comment: When does this error occurs? What are your trying to achieve? What have you tried so far? Please be a bit more specific on your question.